# Percentage validation check function in javascript

Tags: javascript, percentage

I would like to write a function which checks if a number is a percentage. If so then it should return true. Percentages noted as decimals should also return true.

How I would like it to behave:

```
/* input value ... return value */
percentage_check("21%") == true
percentage_check("21") == true
percentage_check("0.21") == true
percentage_check(21) == true
percentage_check(0.21) == true

percentage_check(121) == false //i dont allow above 100%
percentage_check(1.21) == true
percentage_check("twenty") == false
```

How should this function be defined?

```
function percentage_check(n) {
 //code
}
```

Comment: Why should 1.21 return false? Sounds like a valid percentage to me...

Comment: good notice, i changed that, it should be true.

Comment: When someone downvotes then please give a reason

Comment: I think this is off topic. You should do some research on how to use regular expressions and give it a try yourself first before posting to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
function percentage_check(n) {
 if(n.toString().match(/^\d+\.?\d?\d?%?$/) && parseFloat(n)<=100 && parseFloat(n)>=0){
    return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/gN7pA8/1

Comment: `n.match(/^\d+\.?\d?\d?%?$/)` works not with numbers.

Comment: @NinaScholz you're right, I added `toString()`, thanks

Comment: `n.toString().match(/^\d{0,3}(\.\d{1,2})?\%?$/` addresses invalid values like '.' or '1.%'

Answer (score 1):

```js
function percentage_check(n) {
    return (('' + n).match(/^\d+\.?\d*%?$/) || false) && parseFloat(n) >= 0 && parseFloat(n) <= 100;
}

document.write(percentage_check("21%") + '<br>'); // == true
document.write(percentage_check("21") + '<br>'); // == true
document.write(percentage_check("0.21") + '<br>'); // == true
document.write(percentage_check(21) + '<br>'); // == true
document.write(percentage_check(0.21) + '<br>'); // == true
document.write(percentage_check(121) + '<br>'); // == false //i dont allow above 100%
document.write(percentage_check(1.21) + '<br>'); // == true
document.write(percentage_check("twenty") + '<br>'); // == false
document.write(percentage_check("21Eur") + '<br>'); // == false
```